# ajax submit form select on change multi row

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, forms

I Think that I have a problem, I have a table where every is a form and when I change the "select" the update without change the page

the problem that the query upadte only the first row why? chrome write me "Found 152 elements with non-unique id #DO20_FLGST1..." not accept multi form?

```
$risultato = sqlsrv_query($conn, $interrogazione);
```

while ($riga = sqlsrv_fetch_array($risultato, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

```
<form name='contact' action=''>
                      <select name="DO20_FLGST1" id="DO20_FLGST1" >
                        <option value='no' <?=$check0;?>>No</option>
                        <option value='cc' <?=$check1;?>>ComeCli</option>
                        <option value='co' <?=$check2;?>>Contrass</option>
                      </select>
                      <input type=hidden name=numreg id='numreg' value="<?=$riga['DO11_NUMREG_CO99'];?>">
                      <input type=hidden name=do20_flag id='do20_flag' value='do20_flag'>
                      <input name='DO20_NUMST1' type='text' size=4 id='DO20_NUMST1' value='<?=$riga['DO20_NUMST1'];?>'>
                      <input name='cliente' type='hidden' id='cliente' value='<?=$riga['CG16_RAGSOANAG']." ".$riga['DO11_NUMDOC']."/".$riga['DO11_SEZDOC'];?>'>
                      </form>
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("change", "select#DO20_FLGST1", function(){

  var do20_flag     = $('#do20_flag').val();
  var numreg        = $('#numreg').val();
  var DO20_NUMST1   = $('#DO20_NUMST1').val();
  var DO20_FLGST1   = $('#DO20_FLGST1').val();

$.ajax({
     url: 'salva.php',
     type: "post",
      data: { "do20_flag": do20_flag, "numreg": numreg, "DO20_NUMST1": DO20_NUMST1, "DO20_FLGST1": DO20_FLGST1},
     success: function(response) {
          alert('Hai modificato '+$('#cliente').val()); 
     }
});
```

});
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used same `ids` for mutliple elements that's the reason only first value gets submitted .Instead just remove all ids from your html and then you can use  `select[name=DO20_FLGST1]` to trigger any select inside your html with same name and then use **[..closest("form").serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** to get all inputs value where select-box has been changed.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("change", "select[name=DO20_FLGST1]", function() {
  var form_ = $(this).closest("form")
  console.log(form_.serialize())
  $.ajax({
    url: 'salva.php',
    type: "post",
    data: form_.serialize(), //use this to get closest form then use serialize
    success: function(response) {
      alert('Hai modificato ' + form_.find('[name=cliente]').val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='contact' action=''>
  <!--remove all ids-->
  <select name="DO20_FLGST1">
    <option value='no1'>No</option>
    <option value='cc2'>ComeCli</option>
    <option value='co3'>Contrass</option>
  </select>
  <input type=hidden name=numreg value="abc">
  <input type=hidden name=do20_flag value='do20_flag'>
  <input name='DO20_NUMST1' type='text' size=4 value='1>'>
  <input name='cliente' type='hidden' value='1221'>
</form>
<form name='contact' action=''>
  <select name="DO20_FLGST1">
    <option value='no1'>No</option>
    <option value='cc2'>ComeCli</option>
    <option value='co3'>Contrass</option>
  </select>
  <input type=hidden name=numreg value="abc2">
  <input type=hidden name=do20_flag value='do20_flag'>
  <input name='DO20_NUMST1' type='text' size=4 value='1>'>
  <input name='cliente' type='hidden' value='12221'>
</form>
```